# Download ADS8321 in LTspice

Tags: adc, ltspice

How can I download ADS8321 in LTspice? If it's not possible, can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Have you tried TINA-TI?

Comment: yes, i couldn't add it to the library

Comment: What is it you're trying to actually accomplish? Why do you need the ADC in your simulation?

Comment: @Shredder I have to make EKG and this ADS8321 is part of my circuit

Comment: The fact that it's part of your physical circuit doesn't mean it needs to be part of your simulation. An ADC has a relatively well defined equivalent input circuit. It appears like a current load to the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You won't find one, it's an ADC. Spice wasn't really intended for ADCs. If you want to [stimulate one](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simulating-sar-adc-analog-inputs.html&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi_wf-ixZb9AhUMHjQIHTR1DmMQFnoECAIQAg&usg=AOvVaw2GRWO4VXIZiomBL2T69zLA), then stimulate the front end capacitance and resistance as a load. If you really desire a quantized value then use a b-source and subtract the voltage after the front end and then use a floor function to do the rounding